# PHP restructure array of data

Tags: php, chart.js

I have an array of data as follow:

```
array 
  0 => 
    array (size=3)
      'name' => string 'credit_card' 
      'revenue' => string '150' 
      'date' => string 'Apr 2020' 
  1 => 
    array (size=3)
      'name' => string 'cash' 
      'revenue' => string '180' 
      'date' => string 'Apr 2020'
  2 => 
    array (size=3)
      'name' => string 'cash' 
      'revenue' => string '80' 
      'date' => string 'May 2020'
  3 => 
    array (size=3)
      'name' => string 'credit_card'
      'revenue' => string '60' 
      'date' => string 'May 2020'
  4 => 
    array (size=3)
      'name' => string 'cash' 
      'revenue' => string '160' 
      'date' => string 'Jun 2020' 
  5 => 
    array (size=3)
      'name' => string 'credit_card' 
      'revenue' => string '300' 
      'date' => string 'Jul 2020'
```

I would like to restructure this array into the following one (to be used in a multiple Line Chart js):

```
array 
  0 => 
    array (size=3)
      'cash' => string '180' 
      'credit_card' => string '150' 
      'date' => string 'Apr 2020' 
  1 => 
    array (size=3)
      'credit_card' => string '60' 
      'cash' => string '80' 
      'date' => string 'May 2020'
  2 => 
    array (size=3)
      'credit_card' => string '0' 
      'cash' => string '160' 
      'date' => string 'Jun 2020' 
  3 => 
    array (size=3)
      'cash' => string '0' 
      'credit_card' => string '300' 
      'date' => string 'Jul 2020'
```

In my case, since multiple line chartjs requires 2 arrays of number for credit_card and cash as inputs, javascript's map() method can easily do the trick with the above restructured data.
Could anyone kindly share any idea on how to restructure the array? Thx!

Comment: What you try to do?

Comment: This is a matter of a simple iteration and building a new array. Nothing beyond `foreach` and `if` is necessary. Have you tried anything yourself? While we're glad to help when you're stuck, you're still expected to make an effort towards reaching the solution. If you've tried something, please share your efforts and explain where and how it failed to achieve what you want.

Comment: @SlavaRozhnev Hi, I wanna restructure the 1st php array into the 2nd one, thx!

Comment: You've been asked to show attempts, not what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try code below:

```
<?php
$data = array (
  0 => array (
      'name' => 'credit_card',
      'revenue' => '150',
      'date' => 'Apr 2020'
  ),
  1 => array (
      'name' => 'cash',
      'revenue' => '180', 
      'date' => 'Apr 2020'
  ),    
  2 => array (
      'name' => 'cash',
      'revenue' => '80',
      'date' => 'May 2020'
  ),
  3 => array (
      'name' => 'credit_card',
      'revenue' => '60', 
      'date' => 'May 2020'
  ),
  4 => array (
      'name' => 'cash', 
      'revenue' => '160', 
      'date' => 'Jun 2020' 
  ),
  5 => array (
      'name' => 'credit_card', 
      'revenue' => '300', 
      'date' => 'Jul 2020' 
  )
);

$result = array_reduce(
    $data,
    function($res, $d) {
        if (!isset($res[$d['date']])) $res[$d['date']] = [
            'date' => $d['date'],
            'cash' => 0,
            'credit_card' => 0
        ];
        $res[$d['date']][$d['name']] = $d['revenue'];
        return $res;
    },
    []
);

var_export(array_values($result));
```

[share PHP code](https://phpize.online/?phpses=e4081e2ae64b51d22e154423abf808e7&sqlses=null&php_version=php8&sql_version=mysql57)